# An integral equation with zero initial condition implies unique solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Suppose $f,g:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ are two continuous functions satisfying
$$f(x)-g(x) = \int_0^x\frac{g(y)-f(y)}{g(y)f(y)}\;dy$$
for every $x\in[0,\infty)$. How to show that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in[0,\infty)$?

---

This question comes from a problem of proving there is at most one nonnegative solution (if exists) for integral equations
$$f(x)=a(x)+\int_0^x\frac{1}{f(y)}\;dy$$
where $a(x)$ is a given continuous function with $a(0)\geq0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h(x):=f(x)-g(x)$. Then $h'(x)=-\frac{h(x)}{g(x)f(x)}$ so
$$
h(x)=C\exp\left(-\int_0^x \frac{1}{g(y)f(y)}\,dy\right).
$$

Comment: I was thinking similar steps but there are several points not very rigorous. First, $\frac{1}{g(y)f(y)}$ might not be integrable. Second $g(y)$ and $f(y)$ might be zero on a zero measure set, so your differential equation only holds almost surely. Is there a way to make it well-defined and rigorous?

Comment: @William : $f$ and $g$ are continuously differentiable and growing away from zero, so what you propose can not happen. Indeed $f(t)={\rm sign}(f(0))\sqrt{f(0)^2+2t}$, the same for $g$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks for your kind reply! I see what you mean, but actually inside the formula of $f$ and $g$ there is an additional given continuous function $a(x)$. I just thought it has nothing to do with proving uniqueness, so I omit it. Now it seems that I need to add them back. See my modification.

Comment: @LutzLehmann By the way, even if $f$ and $g$ are growing away from zero, it could be the case that the $1/(f\cdot g)$ is not integrable around zero even if $1/f$ and $1/g$ are integrable.

Comment: @William : The day is too late for me, of course the presence of $a(x)$ makes the whole situation somewhat less controllable and less smooth.